# Editing a Registry-Key in HKCU with a App in an App-Package

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge

I programmed a program for windows that switches automatically between the dark and light theme of windows 10. But in an app-package the key doesn't change. Running the app normal without a store-package edits everything fine.

The app edits the Key "AppsUseLightTheme" in HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize at a scheduled time in the background.

Because of the limitations of App-Packages, the App can only read this key, but writing to it remain unchanged.

```
RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize", true);

registryKey.SetValue("AppsUseLightTheme", theme, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

It would be nice, if there is a solution to still change the Theme system wide for the user.

Answer (score 1):

This limitation is currently by design. An app package is not supposed to have any potentially undesired/breaking impact on other apps on the system.

What is your scenario?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Isn't my Scenario already described in the main post? I have a App that should switch the Windows theme at scheduled times in the Background. You can look at the GitHub page for more Details and the Code: https://github.com/Armin2208/Windows-Auto-Night-Mode . It is a small tool and I really want to publish this in the Microsoft Store to reach more users. In the package the app can read the registry key, create the Task sheduler Task, but the app cannot switch the theme. Because I Need to Change the registry key for that. I hope this was a "Scenario description".

Comment: There is no way to do this from a Store app today. Store apps are not supposed to have system-wide impact like this outside of their own app.